# On an average How many times must I throw $r $ die with $N$ faces, such that I see all $N$ faces?

Tags: dice

For an $n$-sided die, the number of rolls needed,
on average $n\log n$ for large n. For one die the question is here: "[A Collection of Dice Problems](http://www.madandmoonly.com/doctormatt/mathematics/dice1.pdf)" by Matthew M. Conroy.

What about $r$ dice?

Comment: Is there any difference between rolling one die $r$ times and rolling $r$ dice?

Comment: No essentially not, but then rolling one die r times will count as 1 throw. @TedShifrin

Comment: @TedShifrin: If the answer for one die is $k$, I think the answer for $r$ dices will be within $[k/r,k/r+1)$, which gives $\lceil \frac{k}{r} \rceil$.

Comment: The expected number $E$ of throws with one die is not an integer anyway. The answer is just $E/k$.